# VMware error "Unable to change power state of virtual machine UPS: Operation inconsistent with current state"

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Yesterday, I pressed the Suspend button of my VMware, which runs on Windows. This morning, when I press the Run button, I get the error message mentioned in the header.

My VMware version is Workstation 15 Pro 15.5.2 build `15785246`.
Between Suspend and Run, the PC has been rebooted.
I am using Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362 Build `18362`.
I am running Ubuntu inside the VMware.
I searched the internet, found a post from 2017 that proposed that I run this command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Since I am completely new to the subject, and I was only able to find one post about it, I would like to hear your opinion as to what I should do?

Comment: I found wmware.log and wmware-1.log. I cannot see anything in them that seems to relate to the problem - although I have no experince with vmware logs.

Answer (score 2):

You might have powered down the host machine or something while the vmware os was running. Right click on the OS, and select open

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: right click on the VMware icon, then run as admin. Then you get into the already started instance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by entering the command

vmrun stop yourpath/yourvm.vmx

This is because an error appeared in which the machine was running in the background.